# Left Right Swipe Animation for Jetpack Compose HorizontalPager to left Page lower high to Center shown in Image link

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack, horizontal-pager

Need to create one horizontal pager which have three pages and the central page contain 80% of width and left and right page contain 10% of a screen. The left and right one will be lower in height from top of the centerpage but bottom should be aligned.

when will swipe it left or right then left/right page will become center page and actually height and suggestion for animation solution on this.

[image]